# Scanning from a file into an array in C

Tags: c

Trying to scan from a file into a C array but I'm getting an error. It worked for me when I was using a file with only numbers on each line like:

```
1.2  
3.4  
5.2
```

But now I have this file:

```
0001:Satriani:Joe:6:38.0
0002:Vai:Steve:1:44.5
0003:Morse:Steve:10:50.0
0004:Van Halen:Eddie:3:25.75
0005:Petrucci:John:8:42.25
0006:Beck:Jeff:3:62.0
```

Here is how I'm trying to scan it into an array, but I get a segmentation fault!

```
FILE *employeesTXT;
int empID[100];
char lastName[100];
char firstName[100];
int payGroup[100];
double hoursWorked[100];

employeesTXT = fopen("employees.txt", "r");
if (employeesTXT == NULL)
{
    printf("Error: file cannot be opened.\n");
} else {
    while (fscanf(employeesTXT, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n", &empID[i], lastName[i], firstName[i], &payGroup[i], &hoursWorked[i]) != EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }

    fclose(employeesTXT);
    numRecords = i;

    for(i = 0; i < numRecords; i++){
        printf("%d - %s - %s - %d - %.2lf\n", empID[i], lastName[i], firstName[i], payGroup[i], hoursWorked[i]);
    }
}
```

It has to be something in this line...  `%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument parameters are wrong for the strings:

```
fscanf(employeesTXT, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%lf\n",
    &empID[i], lastName[i], firstName[i], &payGroup[i], &hoursWorked[i])
```

`lastName` and `firstName` are declared as an array of 100 `char`.  You want those to be strings so you need to define them to be an array of 100 "buffers".

Try changing the declarations to:

```
char lastName[100][50]; /* 50 or whatever the max length you'd expect + 1 */
char firstName[100][50];
```

I believe that should work just like that.

You also have a different issue with `empID`, you're reading the value as a string and not an integer.  In the format, it should be `%d` for integers if these are indeed integers in your input.

Comment: That works now, but now I get a weird output for the beginning. Everything outputs fine, just instead of `0001`, `0002` .. I get random numbers like 185285158481 and 10585871844 etc.

Comment: The problem there is that you're not reading in the number correctly.  I've updated my answer though Aravind touched on it, you're reading that as a string and placing it in an integer which would be incorrect.

Comment: Yes awesome, it works. Thank you! Just one more small error, how do I store the trailing zeros into my empID? Right now it gets rid of the 0's and just prints the integer!

Comment: Change the format string for the number to be `%04d` that way it will be printed using 4 numbers with the leading zeroes included.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
char lastName[100];
char firstName[100];
```

to

```
char lastName[100][100];
char firstName[100][100];
```

Also while reading `empID[i]` don't use `%[^:]`, use `%d` instead.

Comment: To show code, just indent it with 4 spaces or select the code and press the `{}` button or press `Ctrl + K`.  To inline code, wrap it in backticks (`\``).

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, for the names you are assigning each new employees' information into an one dimensional array, thereby overwriting the previous employee's information (except the first character). This eventually leads to your error when you try to assign a long enough name to an index near the end of your array which causing it to write over the last index. You can use a two dimensional array as suggested for the names:

`char lastname[number_of_employees][maximum_length_of_name];`

and each lastname[i] will be a null terminated string.

But, this is what structures are made for.

```
// Define it before main()
struct employee_type{
    int empID;
    char *lastname;
    char *firstname;
    int paygroup;
    double hoursworked;
}

// In main()
struct employee_type employees[100]; // Declare an array of employee_type structures.
```

Comment: Fair enough. Two dimensional arrays it is, and it looks like Jeff has you sorted out on that. Happy coding to you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have addresses as parameters for `fscanf`, this won't work as parameter as it is only a character:

```
   lastName[i]
```

Comment: you're welcome... this is a correct answer, you should try to think a bit before downvoting.

Comment: But like, it's actually not lol, because it works fine without using &lastname[i]. Check Jeff Mercado's answer.

Comment: @eveo: To be fair, he explains why it didn't work... just didn't mention what the fix would be.

Comment: But that's not why it didn't work though, it didn't work because it didn't have the [50] beside it.

Comment: @eveo: I suggest you get a book about c. If you have one already, you should read it.